# Hibernate Reference Column to another table Column With Primary Key

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am trying to build an application with Hibernate + Spring.
I created  a schema and saved as schema.sql :

First Table:

```
` CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `PayingMethods` (
 `PaymentMethodsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `PaymentName` varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
 `CompleteTime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`PaymentMethodsID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Second Table:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `Payed` (
        `PayedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

        `PaymentName` int(11) NOT NULL,

        `Price` int(11) NOT NULL,

        `Where` varchar(500) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`PayedID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`PaymentName`) REFERENCES` 
        PayingMethods`(`PaymentMethodsID`) ON DELETE CASCADE) 

    ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I can run this script on server (at PhPmyadmin) , it creates the 2 table and  properly set the reference.

Can I run this file at the first start of the server ? Now I use :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/import.sql</property>
```

Which creates an empty database then import datas to it. It is not good, because this doesn't set the reference.

My Model classes:

PaymentMethods Table Model :

```
`
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //for autonumber

private int PaymentMethodID;
@Column
private String PaymentName;
@Column
private String CompleteTime;`
```

Payed Table Model:

```
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //for autonumber
private int PayedID;



@Column
private String PaymentName;
@Column
private String price;
@Column
private String where;
```

How to import schema.sql then the import.sql at the first run, or how to set the Reference at Hibernate model ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: do it from spring roo :)

Comment: Hibernate helps to use ORM mapping so you define the relationships (associateions) at Java/Object level and it can generate sample tables for you if you set hbm.ddl = true.

Comment: What do you mean by hbm.ddl=true ?

Do you mean this ? <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

Comment: Yes, thats correct this will initialize the database tables for you when you run the application for the first time. As i understand your question you are asking about the relationship between fields you need to set it at Java/Object level and Hibernate should generate relevant FK constraints for you.